# Transform error in react native when running code in android device

Tags: android, node.js, react-native, reactive-programming

As I am running my first sample reactive native android app on the device and I am getting an error with a red screen, please help me to figure it out. Thanks.

For reference kindly look at the screen below.[image]

And check my error terminal is bellow.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade your `babel-preset-react-native` to `4.0.0` as a dev dependency

```
yarn add --dev babel-preset-react-native@4.0.0
```

and try running it again.

Comment: I tried this but still, I am getting the same error. Thanks. "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "22.4.3",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "jest": "22.4.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
  },

Comment: Can you add your updated `package.json` ? Also clean the cache before this.

Comment: sure - {
  "name": "SampleTwo",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.55.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "22.4.3",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "jest": "22.4.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}

Comment: Last step would be to try these all too `watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-* && rm -rf node_modules/ && npm cache clean && npm install && npm start -- --reset-cache`

Comment: After changing the version of babel-preset-react-native to 4.0.0, cleanup your node_modules directory and do yarn / npm install again.